# Should 'type' be allowed to inherit by both interfaces and classes?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, interface

Using PHP 5.5, if I specify a hierarchy of interfaces and a parallel hierarchy of classes, I end up with child classes that inherit a certain type via more than one relationship.  Does this suggest poor design?  Can it create problems?

For example, see the code:

```
interface foo {}
interface bar extends foo {}

class myFoo implements foo {}
class myBar extends myFoo implements bar {}
```

In this example, myBar inherits the type 'foo' via two relationships:

- It inherits 'foo' from it's concrete parent (myFoo)
- It inherits 'foo' from the interface which it implements (bar)

The reason that I have a 1-to-1 relationship between interfaces and classes is so that I can substitute proxies and mocks for concrete classes at a granular level.  (All my method parameters are expressed in terms of interfaces).

I could stop using inheritance in my interfaces but this seems to go against polymorphism.  In addition, it creates problems when I am using my interfaces to define method signatures (i.e. not just to establish a common type).

Comment: Since interfaces do not have any code, why extend it? You cannot  overload a function in an interface anyway. Decouple foo and bar and you should be fine.

Comment: @JvO Because there may be a legitimate case for wanting to express *"I want this interface to define all the same methods as this other interface, but also a bunch of additional methods."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter either way. Think of it from the perspective of the "consumer" of an interface, not from the abstract idea of the interface itself:

```
function (bar $bar) {
    ...
}
```

This is where the rubber meets the road with interfaces. All this function is interested in is an object which has methods which conform to the methods defined in the `bar` interface. It doesn't care how exactly this object implements these methods, just that it has all the methods that `interface bar` defines. It also doesn't matter which methods are inherited, whether in the interface or the object. The sum aggregate of the instantiated object is all that matters.

Having said that, you may want to think about your interface and class design a little more nonetheless. What you're doing is not wrong per se, but there *may* be a better way to approach interfaces. Don't think of interfaces as a sketch for a class, think of interfaces as a definition of a capability. For that, again, think in terms of the *consumer* of such an interface. For example:

```
function renderThumbnail(Imaginable $item) {
    printf('<img src="%s">', $item->getHighestResolutionImage()->getUrl());
}


interface Imaginable {

    /**
     * @return Image[]
     */
    public function getImages();

    /**
     * @return Image
     */
    public function getHighestResolutionImage();

}
```

This demonstrates one specific *capability* an object may have. *Any* object may have associated images. Any class implementing the `Imaginable` interface simply declares that it can provide an image on request. The `renderThumbnail` function simply needs any object which has an image. It doesn't matter what object gets passed into it, that object may implement a thousand other interfaces as well and be of any type of class, the important part is that it can do this one specific thing.

If you think about it in terms of "`-able`" capability interfaces, it should be obvious that you probably won't end up with two hierarchies running in parallel, and that will probably be the better design.